# mapbox display multiple tooltips onload

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm trying to display each map marker's tooltip onload without the need to hover or click to reveal it. Here is my attempt to chain the openPopup function to bindPopup:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
            popupContent = feature.properties.popupContent;
        }
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent).openPopup();
    }
```

But the tooltips do not appear unless clicked.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nathanbweb/46f2r/4/)

I see that [this page](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/marker-popup-onload/) of documentation offers the following function, but it is only for a single marker, not multiple ones.

```
marker.eachLayer(function(m) {
  m.openPopup();
});
```

How do I display all markers onload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is how popups work in leaflet.

There is a small hack provided in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16707921/128165

```
/***  little hack starts here ***/
L.Map = L.Map.extend({
    openPopup: function (popup) {
        //        this.closePopup();  // just comment this
        this._popup = popup;

        return this.addLayer(popup).fire('popupopen', {
            popup: this._popup
        });
    }
}); /***  end of hack ***/
```

Once you add that to your code you can use

```
for (var o in overlays){
    overlays[o].eachLayer(function (m) {
        m.eachLayer(function(l){l.openPopup();});
    });
}
```

to iterate over all markers in your case and call their `openPopup` method

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/46f2r/6/