# How to hide tooltip for selected Leaflet marker

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I have multiple markers (vessels) on a Leaflet map. Each has popup content (marker title) and tooltip, which are the same (vessel name). The problem is when I click on a marker, it opens the popup showing the title. Then I hover the mouse on the marker, it shows the tooltip which is the same text as the title. This makes the UI become redundant.

[image]

Is there any way or option for the tooltip to make it hidden for the selected/focused marker? I used Leaflet interop with Blazor.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/69648727/1832954 ?

Answer (score 0):

Ty achieving this by  showing and hiding the tooltip based on whether the marker is selected or not.

You could add a function that updates the state of marketer based on whether is selected or not

for example

```
    {
bool isMarkerSelected = false;
}
```

use leaflets events to handle the interraction. When the marker is clicked then set isMarkerSelected to true. When the mouse enters or leaves the marker, show or hide the tooltip based on the value of isMarkerSelected.